# How to delete the npm_cache from window system?

Tags: caching

When I run npm install then npm look into npm cache to install the dependency from local system itself. I want to remove the local npm cache so that it featch the node modules from npm repository ?

- Window Key  + R
- type %AppData%
- it will take user to the app data location.
- delete npm cache from there
- run npm install now

Answer (score 0):

The cached file are stored in `%LocalAppData%\npm-cache` by default in Windows.

To clear this cache use any of [these commands](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache):

```
npm cache clean
// or
npm cache clear
// or
npm cache rm
```

You might need to use `--force` to get it to work.

To verify the cache use:

```
npm cache verify
```